# How to create a one-to-one relationship from X to User

Tags: jhipster

I'm experimenting with jHipster.
I want to create a one-to-one relationship from my entity X to the User entity.

This is definition:

```
"relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipId": 1,
        "relationshipName": "user",
        "otherEntityName": "user",
        "relationshipType": "one-to-one",
        "otherEntityField": "id",
        "ownerSide": true,
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "x"
    }
]
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, it also expects changes in the user entity which is actually managed by jHipster. I don't want to change the generated User code.

I have experimented with many-to-one relationships to User. They don't cause problems because there's no otherEntityRelationshipName field.

```
{
    "relationshipId": 1,
    "relationshipName": "user",
    "otherEntityName": "user",
    "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
    "otherEntityField": "id"
}
```

Suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Anybody?
If not, I'll submit a bug in the jHipster issue tracker soon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. I just tested it with the latest version 2.22.0 of JHipster.
Are you using the latest version of JHipster? What error do you get?

The `"otherEntityRelationshipName": "x"`property is actually ignored by the generator when the other relationship entity is User. Though it is still asked by the generator and this is a bug. I have created an issue in github for this, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2121

Comment: I've tested it with 2.21.0
I'll re-investigate this and hopefully I'll be able to confirm that the otherEntityRelationshipName is indeed ignored.

Thanks for the reply!

Comment: So what is the solution.. ?